# Something makes UITableView to go slowmotion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a UITableView, and sometimes when running the app, the UITableView starts to move in slowmotion. It's not lagging so to speak, but gets very unresponsive and moves at 20% of the normal speed. I have no idea why. The code and app is very complex, so it's hard to post code.

Just wondering if anyone have any suggestion on how to track down the error, or had similar problems?

Also, when this happens, all other tableview controller gets slow too throughout the app. Its a tabbar application.

Thanks

Some update:

If I'm in one tableView and push to a detail view... that view will go slowmotion. However, if i switch to another tabview, and then go back to the previous view, It runs smooth again.

Comment: Without seeing actual code we can just give you assumptions whats wrong would be with code. Please post code.

Comment: You say the code and app is very complex - probably there's your problem.

Comment: Assumptions are a waste of our time.

Comment: Show some code you have in **viewWillAppear**, **viewWillDisappear**, etc. Maybe you have some animation sequence set somewhere that you are overlooking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible reason I can think of without seeing code.

1. You have toggled **Slow Animations** in the iOS Simulator. This will slow down the animations of the OS. I don't think it applies to
   UIView animations though set in code *(at least I have not seen this
   case with my animations code)*.

   Unfortunately, there is no indication if this is actually set (besides the fact that animations are SLOW), for example a check mark in the menu like when you toggle **Color Blended Layers**

   [image] [image]
2. You have set UIView animations somewhere and added an extra **0** perhaps, something like instead of `[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0` you have `[UIView animateWithDuration:20.0`.

Comment: I tried to remove all my animations, which seems to fix the problem. Many thanks